# how to increase space between nav-pills bootsrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, navbar

my nav pills are to close and i want them spread out, any way i can change the font and font size as well?

```
 <div id = "page">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

   <div>
```

Comment: This would work: .nav-pills > li > a {margin-left:??px;margin-right:??px;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create new CSS file and link it in your HTML. Then write this code in it:

```
.nav-pills li {
    margin-left: 5px; //use whatever you want
} 

.nav-pills a {
    //use font-family and font-size to change font and size of it.
}
```

Just remember to link this new css file after bootstrap, so it would overwrite it.

Answer (score 3):

you can customize margin between each li like that:

```
.nav-pills>li+li {
  margin-left: 10px; // 2px by default
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do, just replace ?? with the number of your choice.

```
.nav-pills > li > a { margin-left:??px;margin-right:??px; }
```